# Look for an example of a surface which is neither a closed subset of $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ nor a proper subset of a larger connected surface.

Tags: differential-geometry

This is the problem from Curves and Surfaces(Montiel, Ros). The hint suggests the surface $S$ parametrized as

$$X(u,v) = (e^{-u}cos(u), e^{-u}sin(u), v)$$

to be the answer. Though I understand that the surface is not a closed subset of $\mathbb{R}^3$, I don't understand why $S$ does not have a larger connected surface that contains $S$. I guess it should have something to do with the limit points of $S$, but I am not perfectly sure. Could anybody help me with this problem?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! <> To start, are you happy with the picture of the logarithmic spiral $r = e^{-\theta}$ in polar coordinates, and do you see how this curve is not part of a larger connected curve?

Comment: I actually came up with a solution, using the fact that the surface that is containing $S$ should have a contain a limit point $p$ of $S$, which leads to a contradiction because there is no inverse projection as a homeomorphism that covers p.

Comment: Btw, I appreciate your help!